# Type the full pathname of a JDK installation when run SQL Devoloper?

Tags: java, linux, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have problem when run Oracle Sql developer by `./sqldeveloper.sh` i'm using ubuntu 16.4 with 64 bit arch so i downlode it from Oracle page as jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz  ,, then i run this command after extract it by `ln -sf /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_121 /opt/java/jdk` , Also i go to gedit this file like this 
`gedit /root/.sqldeveloper/4.1.5/product.conf` and uncomment and add the path `SetJavaHome /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_121/`

problem when i run `./sqldeveloper.sh`

Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /root/.sqldeveloper/4.1.5/product.conf

Comment: Doesn't the path you supply have to point to the `bin` directory? What happens when you supply the full `/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin` when prompted? (And what is the relevance of your `ln` command?)

Comment: @AlexPoole The path should be the installation directory of JDK, i.e., without the `bin` directory.

Comment: What is the problemd you're experiencing?

Comment: after i run `/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin` still same Error

Comment: please help me problem still unsolved  !!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enough space and no errors when extracting jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz . I had the same error but did notice I was running out of space, so the JDK installation was incomplete